# Build JSON on grails/groovy

Tags: json, rest, grails

I would like help with how to do a POST in Grails, I have no idea how to start, I need to pass a JSON to the HEADER with some information.

How to build a dynamic JSON?

How can I pass a JSON on a POST?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: add some info. What do you mean by `doing a POST`? your form in view as POST? do a POST to outer domain? And You can build JSON many ways. If you want to render it to a view, go with `render string as JSON`; (or obj.. or array). And what is your Grails version? Be more specific. A lot of things are unclear

Comment: I'm going to consume an external API, sending data from my DB attributes to a grails class.
I'm using version 2.3.11.
I need to build a FORM with lots of keys and arrays.

Comment: I still use httpbuilder for this (https://github.com/jgritman/httpbuilder)